# solr 3.6.1 nested queries

Tags: solr

I have a case where i need to find the results of a query that search for a exact phrase + other words, for example, if i have a keyword like:

*"how about" tomorrow morning*

the results that should be fetched should match these criteria:

- containing exact phrase *how about*.
- containing word *tomorrow*.
- containing word *morning*.

Can anybody explain to me how to do this? I tried:

```
q=exactText:"how+about" AND content:tomorrow+morning
q=exactText:"how+about" AND _query_:"{!dismax qf=content pf=content v=$qq}"&qq=tomorrow+morning
```

but the results that i got:

1. Documents always contain phrase *how about* plus *tomorrow*.
2. Documents always contain phrase *how about* plus *morning*.
3. Documents always contain phrase *how about* plus *tomorrow* and *morning*.

The correct result should only be number 3. Please, help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try querying:

```
exactText:"how+about" AND content:tomorrow AND content:morning
```